# SwiftUI: WebP images are not loading in WatchOS

Tags: ios, swiftui, watchos-2

Tried to load WebP Image like in this article,

https://www.hackingwithswift.com/forums/swiftui/loading-images/3292

is working fine in iOS App target but not in WatchOS Extension target.

```
if let image = UIImage(data: loader.data) {
   return Image(uiImage: image)
} else {
    return failure
}
```

*UIImage(data: loader.data)* will always nil in WatchOS extension target

Can someone help me out how we can load webp image in WatchApps?

Comment: The likely conclusion would be that webp isn't supported in WatchOS

Comment: that's not what the docs say at: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uniformtypeidentifiers/uttype/3551599-webp

Comment: @workingdog it says that the Uniform Type Identifier for webp is available on WatchOS.  That doesn't mean that `UIImage` on that platform knows how to decode one.  There is a UTI for [perl scripts](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uniformtypeidentifiers/uttype/3551545-perlscript) but you can't run them on WatchOS natively

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImageWebPCoder swift Package Manger, To load WebP image in WatchApp